# LINQ to SQL Query Where Clause

Tags: linq-to-sql

I would like to create a single query that "adjusts" it's where clause based on a tuple.  The first item in the tuple contains a enum value indicating the field in which to filter.  The second tuple item is the filter value.

Notice the query below does not work:

```
        var query = from p in db.Categories
        where ( QueryBy.Item1 == CategoryFields.Name        && p.Name        == (string)(QueryBy.Item2) ) ||
              ( QueryBy.Item1 == CategoryFields.Id          && p.Id          == (long)(QueryBy.Item2)   ) ||
              ( QueryBy.Item1 == CategoryFields.Description && p.Description == (string)(QueryBy.Item2) ) ||
              ( QueryBy.Item1 == CategoryFields.SortOrder   && p.SortOrder   == (int)(QueryBy.Item2)    ) 
        select...

        if (query.Count() == 1) // ERRORS HERE CONVERSION OF INT
```

A similar query with only this where clause change will works:

```
        var query = from p in db.Categories
        where ( QueryBy.Item1 == CategoryFields.Name        && p.Name        == (string)(QueryBy.Item2) )
        select...

        if (query.Count() == 1) // Works HERE
```

Any idea what could be wrong?  Can it be that LINQ where clause perform a short-circuit evaluation and thus the cast of item2 fails?  Is there a better way to accomplish my overall goal of adjusting where clause?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

LINQ to SQL isn't smart enough to optimize your query and generate it dynamically based on the value of your `QueryBy.Item1`. It will simply  generate a SQL query let SQL server decide this for itself.

When you know that, the error makes sense, since it's impossible for one single value to be castable to both `int`, `long`, and `string`.

In your case you would be better of dynamically generating the right `where` clause. You can do this with the [PredicateBuilder](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx):

```
IQueryable<Category> query = db.Categories;

var whereClause = PredicateBuilder.False<Category>();

switch (QueryBy.Item1)
{
    case CategoryFields.Name:
        long id = (string)QueryBy.Item2;
        whereClause = whereClause.Or(p => p.Name == name);
        break;

    case CategoryFields.Id:
        string name = (string)QueryBy.Item2;
        whereClause = whereClause.Or(p => p.Id == id);
        break;

    case CategoryFields.Description:
        string des = (string)QueryBy.Item2;
        whereClause =
            whereClause.Or(p => p.Description == des);
        break;

    case CategoryFields.Id:
        string sort = (int)QueryBy.Item2;
        whereClause =
            whereClause.Or(p => p.SortOrder == sort);
        break;
}

query = query.Where(whereClause);
```

Comment: Thanks Steven! This works with one change.  The last line: "query = query.Where(whereClause);"  Does seem to filter the query.  So I moved the switch statement about the query and changed the query to: "IQueryable<Category> query = (db.Categories...).Where(whereClause);"